# GCC -std=gnu99 error

Tags: gcc, c

I'm trying to compile a C code with this command `gcc -Wall -m32 -std=gnu99 -o <filename> <filename>`

Instead of getting an output file, I get this.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find Scrt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libgcc_s.so.1 when searching for libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Compiling with `-std=c11` works perfectly fine, but not with -`std=gnu99`.

Comment: Have you installed `gcc-multilib`?

Answer (score 0):

Bascially this means that you don't have 32 bits support on your system, just 64 bits.

With main.c

```
/*  extern void start();                                                     */

int main()
{
/*  start();                                                                 */
}
```

and

```
gcc -m32 main.c -o main
```

I got on an ubuntu 18.04 with just gcc installed:

```
> ~/PROJECT2/ciforthcvs$ gcc -m32 main.c -o main /usr/bin/ld: cannot
> find Scrt1.o: No such file or directory /usr/bin/ld: cannot find
> crti.o: No such file or directory /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit
> status
```

after

```
su
# apt install multi-lib
```

Everything went nice, and I could run my do nothing program.

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
find / -iname='*Scrit1.o*' 2>/dev/null
find / -iname='*criti.o*' 2>/dev/null
```

modify your gcc command to read

```
gcc -Wall -m32 -std=gnu99 -o <filename> <filename> /some-path/Scrit1.o /some-other-path/criti.o
```